# Puppeteer save file downloaded from background_page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, puppeteer, headless

I am using Puppeteer to click a button on page, after that it auto opens a pop up and auto download file.

How to capture that file? I want to save it on server by headless mode.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Post code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: '/home/me/stuff'});
```

The file will be stored in that directory, so you can check for it later.